# How to assign selected value to "Select" when value is of class object in angular 2

Tags: angular2-template, angular2-forms

Using angular 2.2.4 from following links learned select list of class object:

[How can I get new selection in "select" in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33700266/4773561)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35945293/4773561

[Angular 2 Dropdown Options Default Value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35978450/4773561)

& implemented as follows

```
<select id="st" name="state" [(ngModel)]="selectedState" (ngModelChange)="onStateSelectedForVanue($event)">
    <option *ngFor="let state of states" 
            [ngValue]="state">{{state.name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

here 'states' is list of State Class object

```
export class State {
 public id:number;
 public name:string;
}
```

this is list of class

```
public states : State[]= [];
```

for states getting value from Service,up to this code I get drop-down of 'state-name'.Now I want to show **'Default'** of **'Pre-selected'** State.For that created **selectedState** Class Object and assign through [(ngModel)] or [ngModel]

```
public selectedState: State;
```

in constructor follwing value assign:

```
this.selectedState = new State();
this.selectedState.id = 12;
this.selectedState.name = 'Goa';
```

and states list getting from  ngOnInit() but default, **no list item(state) is getting selected**

also tried adding following code in

```
<option></option>
[selected]="state.name === selectedState.name" with reference link
```

[Set initially selected item in Select list in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37663158/4773561)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37666951/4773561

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37663411/4773561

still not getting pre-selected state

what is wrong in code ?

Comment: onInit you subscribe to some service and then get the data for the select?

Comment: @Aravind yes !!

Comment: I have the same problem...
But for the last element in the dropdown it works and I don't know why...
DId you find a solution?

Comment: @5im yes,but using id <select  [ngModel]="selected?.id" (ngModelChange)="onStateSelected($event)"> 
             <option *ngFor="let state of states" [ngValue]="state.id">{{state.name}}</option> 
         </select>