# Defaulting select option

Tags: angular

In my Angular program, I want to default the option that's selected in my select to be "Current". In everything that I've seen online, what I have should work and it just defaults as null. I've also tried `selected = "selected"` and that doesn't work either. Why doesn't it and how do I fix it?

```html
<select class="form-control" id="empStatus" [(ngModel)]="newEmp.EmpStat" name="empStatus">
    <option value="Current" selected>Current</option>
    <option value="Terminated">Terminated</option>
</select>
```

Comment: which version of angularjs are you using?

Comment: @AquilaSagitta Angular 4

Comment: You need to set your `newEmp.EmpStat` property to the value you want selected, so `"Current"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 Dropdown Options Default Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35978450/angular-2-dropdown-options-default-value)

Comment: @tymeJV okay, thanks a lot. that's what I thought, I just wasn't sure where to do it, but I ended up putting it in my `ngOnInit()`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44458036/356380

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to (if coding in XHTML file):

```
<select class="form-control" id="empStatus" [(ngModel)]="newEmp.EmpStat" name="empStatus">
<option value="Current" selected="selected">Current</option>
<option value="Terminated">Terminated</option>
```

As seen here:
[How can I set the default value for an HTML <select> element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518002/how-can-i-set-the-default-value-for-an-html-select-element)