# Selected not work in Angular 2 select

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

Having a dropdown with option populated using ngFor in **angular 2** code. I need any particular option at any given index to be selected by default.

I have used **[attr.selected]="i == 0"** ,but it **selects last option** instead first one.

> Here is My code

```
<select id="roles" required formControlName="userRole">
    <option *ngFor="let roles of URoles;let i = index" [attr.selected]="(i==0)" [value]="roles._id">{{ roles.name }}</option>
</select>
```

What could be the problem ? Why first option not selected ?

Comment: why to use ng-container in this case? just add the *ngFor to the option element

Comment: maybe this answer could be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37663158/set-initially-selected-item-in-select-list-in-angular2

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding select is working as it should work . so an easy solution will be

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let roles of universityAllRoles;let first = first"<option [attr.selected]="first" [value]="roles._id">{{ roles.name }}</option></ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help you

```
<select id="roles" required formControlName="userRole">
 <option *ngFor="let roles of URoles;let i = index;" [value]="roles._id" selected="i==0">{{roles.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Also no need for `ng-container` here.

Answer 2 -
If you need `attr.selected` attribute to be working use the code below :

```
<select id="roles" required formControlName="userRole">
 <option *ngFor="let roles of URoles;let i = index;" [value]="roles._id" [attr.selected]="i == 1">{{roles.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: any issues with the solution provided ?

Answer (score 0):

Pls try this

```
<select id="roles" required formControlName="userRole">
    <option *ngFor="let roles of URoles" [selected]="roles._id == 0" [value]="roles._id" >{{ roles.name }}</option>
</select>
```

Worked for me. Hope this will work for you.